# django: How to hook save button for Model admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Model with a "status" field. When the user users the Admin app to modify an instance,  how to I hook onto the "Save" button click so that I could update "status" to a value that's dependent on the logged in user's username?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Override your modeladmin's `save_model`-method:

```py
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):       
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        user = request.user 
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if not change:    # new object
            instance.status = ....
        else:             # updated old object
            instance.status = ...
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`pre_save` signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save). Granted, it will be called on every instance save operation, not only from admin, but it does apply to your situation.

Answer (score 4):

ModelAdmin.save_model() provides just what I need

Answer (score 0):

```py
form.cleaned_data.get('categories')
```

This gets the value directly in the ModelAdmin.save_model